# Local storage foreach in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried everything to understand this but just can't. How do I know what product my user clicks? Let's say he clicks 5 time on a product(=iphone), my page responds with 5 items in the shoppingcart(that work's) but when i go to the page: shopping cart I have nothing. I have read thousands of manuals about local storage in Laravel but just can't get it. Can somebody please give me an example with my code?

```
@foreach($shopGSM as $shopGSM)
{{ $shopGSM->naam }}
<a href="addToCart">
@endoreach
```

Comment: `localStorage` is HTML5 feature, you need to store your info either `Db` or a `Session` to be persistent through the pages

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use `Session` to store the user's clicked data.

Use the `session()->set()` to store any data on session and use `session()->get()` to get data from session.

More details here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session#basic-usage

Alternatively, you can see how I implemented a cart system using session on one of my projects at Github: https://github.com/SumonMSelim/laravel5-basic-crud/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/CartController.php